# Explicit examples of higher genus Drinfeld modules?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, function-fields

Let $C$ is a smooth, projective, geometrically irreducible curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $\infty$ a closed point of $C$. A Drinfel'd module over $A = H^0(C, \mathcal{O}_C)$ is an injective homomorphism $A \rightarrow L\{\tau\} \cong \text{End}_L(\mathbb{G}_a)$, where $L$ is some characteristic $p$ field.

If $C = \mathbb{P}^1$, then $A = \mathbb{F}_q[t]$ and it is easy to write down such a homomorphism (one only needs to specify the image of $t$). However, if $C$ is a higher genus curve, then I don't see how to write down an example. Even for the case of a hyperelliptic curve, it's not clear to me how to show that there are any examples of Drinfel'd modules.

Question: how can one explicitly write down Drinfel'd modules for higher genus curves, or at least show abstractly that plenty of nontrivial examples exist?

Answer (score 2):

You can find explicit constructions of Drinfeld modules on elliptic curves in David Hayes' paper [*On the reduction of rank-one Drinfeld modules*](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1991-57-195/S0025-5718-1991-1079021-7/S0025-5718-1991-1079021-7.pdf). The simplest example (page 345 of *op. cit.*) is obtained by considering the elliptic curve $E/\Bbb F_2$ defined by the (affine) equation
$$Y^2+Y=X^3+X+1.$$
Denote by $\infty$ the point at infinity of $E$ and by $K=\Bbb F_2(E)$ its field of rational functions. Set finally $A=H^0(E-\{\infty\},\mathcal O_E)=\Bbb F_2[X,Y]$. We can then define a Drinfeld module $\varphi:A\to K\{\tau\}$ by setting
$$\begin{cases}
\varphi_X=X+(X^2+X)\tau+\tau^2,\\
\,\\
\varphi_Y=Y+(Y^2+Y)\tau+X(Y^2+Y)\tau^2+\tau^3.
\end{cases}$$